# How to set java home in Chef

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I have the below code in chef where I want to set `JAVA_HOME` but only if its not set already. When I run the below it says its ran successfully but does not set java_home. The java_home commands sets correctly if I run manually.

Even if I remove the not if it runs without error but does not set `JAVA_HOME`.

```
bash 'set_JAVA_HOME' do
  code <<-EOH
    JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
    only_if code
    <<-EOH 'echo $JAVA_HOME' ==0
EOH
end
```

Comment: Are you using the java community cookbook? https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java

Comment: No I'm not using the JAVA cookbook.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables only work one-way, they are sent from parent to child when a process forks, but not the other way around. This code is effectively a no-op. Either set the variable in Chef's environment `ENV['JAVA_HOME'] = ...` or use the `environment` property on specific resources.